# Cannot close duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, close-reasons

I just tried to close [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901183/create-a-prolog-program-to-solve-the-peg-jump-puzzle-described-here-the-game-ha) as duplicate of [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36879616/create-a-prolog-program-that-solves-the-peg-jump-puzzle) question. But I cannot and get as justification

> This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer

I sometimes encounter such waves of identical questions probably coming from the very same course. Since it is impossible to close one of the questions prior to answering it, efforts to answer it will not be concentrated.